# Centering an underlined title

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, underline

The goal is to center the main title in the cover page, however, this has been proven *quite* the challenge.

#### What the problem is

Most of the approaches I've tried end up in the same way: **the title overflowing to the right without adding a line break.** Below is the output of `\uline{\par\Large{\textbf{\@title}}}\\`, where title is defined as *A VERY LONG TITLE THAT DOES NOT BREAK INTO MULTIPLE LINES EVEN THOUGH IT SHOULD*:
[image: The problem]

The above format is specified and cannot be modified. However, I've narrowed down the problem to be the underlining, as any other commands without any form of underlining (`\underline{}`, `\ul{}`, `\uline{}`, etc. ) all have the desired effect, minus the underlining. The current class is **book**.

#### What has been tried

- Refactoring of the command above.
- The `ulem` and `soul` packages, along with the default underlining options.
- Wrapping the title in a minipage.
- `\centerline`.
- Making a wrapper for `\@title`

#### What has *not* been tried

- `titling` package.
- Last resources: a pre-underlined font; starting from scratch.

[Minimal working example](https://github.com/POWRFULCOW89/LaTeX-underlined-title-MWE)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimal working example (MWE) of your current code for us to work on.

Comment: It is easier to make a custom title by NOT using \maketitle at all.  titlepage OTOH is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your `titlepage` to get a **bold**, large, undeline title plus the rest of the layout with a few changes to `Titulation`, and keep using `\maketitle`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,openright,11pt, oneside, spanish]{book}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{Titulacion} % Formatting    
\usepackage{ulem}

\title{\uline{A VERY LONG TITLE THAT DOES NOT BREAK INTO MULTIPLE LINES EVEN THOUGH IT SHOULD}}

\begin{document}    
\maketitle  
\end{document}
```

This is `Titulation.sty`

```
   \ProvidesPackage{Titulacion}

  \renewcommand\maketitle{%
    \begin{titlepage}
        \fontfamily{lmr}
        \fontsize{14}{30}\selectfont  
            
        \hfill\vspace{.1\textwidth}     
        \centering      
        \vspace{11mm}   
            
        {\bfseries \@title}
        
        \vspace{11mm}
        TITULACIÓN INTEGRAL\\
        \vspace{2mm}\
        
        PARA OBTENER EL TÍTULO DE:
            \vspace{11mm}
            
        PRESENTA:\\ 
        \vspace{11mm}   
    ASESOR:\\   
    \end{titlepage}
}%
\endinput
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo), getting rid of a custom `\maketitle` worked like a charm. Find the new changes implemented below:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,openright,11pt, oneside, spanish]{book}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
\title{\uline{A VERY LONG TITLE THAT DOES NOT BREAK INTO MULTIPLE LINES EVEN THOUGH IT SHOULD}}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Which produce the following result:

[image]

Comment: You don't give enough of your original attempt to make a strong diagnosis, but from what you gave, I think changing it to `\par\Large{\textbf{\uline{\@title}}}` would probably work.

Comment: Didn't work when plugged as-is, most likely due to the intrincate \maketitle I have set up, as [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo) pointed out. I'll keep it in mind for the next template though.